# Skip backup_manifest task in rails capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, webpacker

I trying to deploy rails app through capistrano. All assets (css, js and images) build by webpacker. I removed app/assets folder and now deploy failed when capistrano trying to backup manifest. This task running always https://github.com/capistrano/rails/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake

If I enable sprockets `require "sprockets/railtie"` everything is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As explained in the capistrano-rails README](https://github.com/capistrano/rails#usage), if you don't use the asset pipeline, then exclude `capistrano/rails/assets` from your Capfile. In other words:

```
# Instead of this:
require "capistrano/rails"

# Require only these:
require "capistrano/bundler"
require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
```

However, if you are using Webpacker, then there is a good chance that you still need to run asset-pipeline tasks. Notably, you still probably need to run `assets:precompile` during deployment, in order to trigger the webpack build.

In this case, you would need a more precise exclusion of the `backup_manifest` task. Following [the instructions in the official Capistrano docs](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/overriding-capistrano-tasks/), you can clear the default implementation as follows:

```
# In deploy.rb
Rake::Task["deploy:assets:backup_manifest"].clear_actions
```